# Magento design - new homepage columns

Tags: templates, layout, magento, magento-1.4

I want to make a custom design for my magento store like this :

[image]

How can I proceed to do that, specially for the products from category1 and category2, I want there a new header for this list, with a little images, not like the standard category grid...

Thanks a lot for help;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create CMS page.
- Switch to the Design mode. Select Layout - 1 column.
- Edit Layout Update XML

  ```
  <block type="cms/block" name="block1_static">
      <action method="setBlockId"><id>cms_block1-static</id></action>
  </block>


  <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="left.callout.wrapper" translate="label">
      <action method="setElementId"><value>hompage-left-callout</value></action>
      <block type="core/template" name="left.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">
          <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/left_banner_1.gif</src></action>
      </block>
  </block>


  <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="center.wrapper" translate="label">
      <action method="setElementId"><value>hompage-center</value></action>
      <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page"><action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action></block>
      <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="home.reports.product.viewed" alias="product_viewed" template="reports/home_product_viewed.phtml" after="product_new"><action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action></block>
  </block>


  <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="right.callout.wrapper" translate="label">
      <action method="setElementId"><value>hompage-right-callout</value></action>
      <block type="core/template" name="right.callout" template="callouts/right_col.phtml">
          <action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/right_banner_1.gif</src></action>
      </block>
  </block>
  ```

There is two blocks for example - viewed products and new products. There is not default block to show products from specific category in Magento. You should create this block and template for it and use this block at place of examples block.

Position of blocks you may align with css. Each block will be wrapped with div with specific ID. ElementId and ElementClass you may set wrapper block.